# Algorithm to group people based on their preference

Tags: algorithm, grouping

I need an algorithm to group people in tables based on their preference. Each person vote sorting the tables from the favorite to the worse.
For example if there are 4 tables in total one person vote is like:

```
Alice{ table1 => 2, table2 => 4, table3=>1, table4=>3}
```

which means she would like to be put on table3 and really dislikes table2

The conditions are:

- Everyone must be in a group
- All groups must have the same number of people (tollerance of 1)
- Maximize the global 'happiness'

Trying to sort this out I defined happiness as points, each person will have happiness 10 if they will be put on their favorite table, 6 on their second choice, 4 on the third and 1 on the last.

```
happiness[10, 6, 4, 1]
```

The global happiness is the sum of each person's happiness.

Comment: why am i getting downvotes? If anyone see a similar question please point me to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use integer linear programming.
There are many solvers out there for ILP, for example SCIP (http://scip.zib.de/).

You would have binary variable for each assigment, i.e.
[image: xij] = 1 if person i was assigned to table j (and 0 is it was not assigned).

Your goal is to maximize total happiness, i.e. sum of weights multiplied by [image: xij]

Now you have write some conditions to ensure, that:

- each person is assigned to exactly one table, i.e. sum of [image: xij] for each i is equal to one.
- all tables have similar number of persons (you can determine possible ranges for number of persons beforehand), i.e. some of [image: xij] for each j is in defined range.

Comment: I see your point but I still don't know how to code this kind of conditions

Comment: Added couple of edits, but I recommend to read some tutorial on integer linear programming.
Like: http://scip.zib.de/download/files/scip_intro_01.pdf http://www.math.clemson.edu/~mjs/courses/mthsc.440/integer.pdf

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, i'll take a good look at those